# How to clear a dropdown menu in Selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to clear the data inside a dropdown menu of select type, but i cannot use select.clear() as it returns an error "Element must be user-editable in order to clear it", which makes total sense. Does any of you know what command to use to clear the respective field?

Comment: If you have a blank option, select that. From your error guessing you have a plain select dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

If your element has a `<select>` tag, you can use the Select class for interaction.

```
// first, initialize the WebElement (using the appropriate selector type, this is just an example)
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("elementId"));

// next, pass it to the Select object
Select selectElement = new Select(element);

// then, select an option from the element
selectElement.selectByVisibleText("Option Text");
```

we can also select by index or value ([documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html))

```
// finally, to clear your selection, try:
selectElement.deselectAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have need to use **deselectAll()** method to unchecked / clear all selected single / all Drop Down / Multi select options if by default selected any option within code.

```
Select DropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Drp_ID")));

DropDown.deselectAll();
```